# Is there a way to reduce the gap between double hlines (\hline\hline) in the tabular environment?

Tags: tables, spacing, rules

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c | c}
    cell 1,1  & cell 1,2\\
    \hline\hline
    cell 2,1  & cell 2,2\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I would like to reduce the gap shown in the table above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This separation is specifically called `\doublerulesep`, with the default set to `2\p@` (or `2pt`). In fact, the gap is actually `\doublerulesep-\arrayrulewidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c | c}
  cell 1,1  & cell 1,2\\
  \hline\hline
  cell 2,1  & cell 2,2\\
\end{tabular}

\setlength{\doublerulesep}{2\arrayrulewidth}
\begin{tabular}{c | c}
  cell 1,1  & cell 1,2\\
  \hline\hline
  cell 2,1  & cell 2,2\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In the above example, `\doublerulesep` is set to twice `\arrayrulewidth`, leading to a gap equivalent to a single `\arrayrulesep` between the two horizontal rules.

---

From [`source2e`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf), section **58.2 `array` and `tabular` environments** (p 247):

> ARRAY PARAMETERS:
>
> - `\doublerulesep` : space between adjacent rules in `array` or `tabular`
>
> SPECIAL ARRAY COMMANDS:
>
> - `\hline` : draws a horizontal line between rows. Must appear either
>     before the first entry (to appear above the first row) or
>     right after a `\\` command. If followed by another `\hline`,
>     then adds a `\vskip` of `\doublerulesep`.

Comment: Oops. That looks like something I could have looked up myself. I have searched Google and couldn’t find anything so I thought it was more involved. Thanks for your answer.